# Displaying image with alpha channel in x11 window

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I've created a window with a transparent background and can make it borderless but first, I want to display an image that is just uint32* in it. However, I got this error message below.

When I try using XPutImage it says

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  72 (X_PutImage)
  Serial number of failed request:  15
```

but I don't know why.

Here is my code if anybody wants to see it:

```cpp
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint32_t height = 64;
    uint32_t width = 64;

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.background_pixel = 0;

    Window win = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, width, height, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
    XSelectInput(display, win, StructureNotifyMask);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, win, 0, 0);

    //attr.override_redirect = True;
    //XChangeWindowAttributes(display, win, CWOverrideRedirect, &attr);

    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, win, &wm_delete_window, 1);

    XMapWindow(display, win);

    int32_t data[64 * 64];


    XImage *image = XCreateImage(display, DefaultVisual(display, DefaultScreen(display)), 8, ZPixmap, 0, (char *) data, width, height, 32, 0);

    XPutImage(display, win, DefaultGC(display, DefaultScreen(display)), image, 0, 0, 0, 0,width, height);

    XFlush(display);

    int keep_running = 1;
    XEvent event;
    while (keep_running) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        //to-do
    }`

    XDestroyWindow(display, win);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using inconsistent depth, gc, and visual values. Make sure you are using the visual you have matched, the GC you have created, and the depth of the visual whenever you need one of those, Do not use default values.

Here is somewhat fixed code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    uint32_t height = 64;
    uint32_t width = 64;

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    XVisualInfo vinfo;
    XMatchVisualInfo(display, DefaultScreen(display), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

    printf ("Depth = %d\n", vinfo.depth);

    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), vinfo.visual, AllocNone);
    attr.border_pixel = 0;
    attr.background_pixel = 0;

    Window win = XCreateWindow(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), 0, 0, width, height, 0, vinfo.depth, InputOutput, vinfo.visual, CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWBackPixel, &attr);
    XSelectInput(display, win, StructureNotifyMask|ExposureMask);
    GC gc = XCreateGC(display, win, 0, 0);

    //attr.override_redirect = True;
    //XChangeWindowAttributes(display, win, CWOverrideRedirect, &attr);

    Atom wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", 0);
    XSetWMProtocols(display, win, &wm_delete_window, 1);

    XMapWindow(display, win);

    int32_t data[64 * 64] = {0};

    XImage *image = XCreateImage(display, vinfo.visual, vinfo.depth,
                                 ZPixmap, 0, (char *) data, width, height, 32, 0);

    XFlush(display);

    int keep_running = 1;
    XEvent event;
    while (keep_running) {
        XNextEvent(display, &event);
        if (event.type == Expose)
        {
            XPutImage(display ,win, gc, image, 0, 0, 0, 0,width, height);
        }
    }

    XDestroyWindow(display, win);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```